# Android View does not show

Tags: android

I have this Android Activity layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#184A64">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#F1CF2F"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descLogoTop"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logoTop" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoBot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#F1CF2F"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descLogoBot"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logoBot" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="103dip"
        android:layout_height="62dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#F1CF2F"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This xml defines a layout with a top rectangle with a log in it, and also a bottom rectangle with a logo in it. Those two elements are displayed correctly. But the middle component is a Linear Layout with a TextView, then an Image, and then 2 TextViews. This component doesn't show. The Java code for the activity goes like this:

```
public class NewsActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null; 
private Runnable viewNews;
private Bundle bundle;
private News m_news = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_activity);

     bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    viewNews = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            getNews();
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewNews, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewsActivity.this,    
            this.getString(R.string.wait), this.getString(R.string.receiving, true));

}

public void getNews() {

    m_news = new News();
    m_news.setNewsTitle(bundle.getString("title"));
    m_news.setNewsText(bundle.getString("text"));
    m_news.setNewsDate(bundle.getString("date"));
    m_news.setNewsPhoto(bundle.getString("photo"));

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_activity, null);

    try{
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);

        if (iv != null) {
            try{
                Bitmap bmp = Utils.getBitmapFromURL("http://www.myServer.com/IMG/" + m_news.getNewsPhoto());
                if (bmp == null){
                    Log.i("PHOTO ERROR", "http://www.myServer.com/IMG/" + m_news.getNewsPhoto());
                }
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);                     
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("IMAGE ERROR", e.getMessage() + " - " + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
        if (tt != null) {
            tt.setText(m_news.getNewsTitle());
        }
        if(bt != null){
            bt.setText(m_news.getNewsText());
        }   
        TextView dt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data);         
        Date nd = new Date(Long.parseLong(m_news.getNewsDate())*1000);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(nd);
        dt.setText(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR NEWS", e.getMessage());
    }

    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
}
```

What I am doing here is to extract some data from the bundle (it works properly), and then set contents to the TextViews and the ImageView. But, when I test this on the emulator the Image and TextViews are empty.

I've checked the calls

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
```

and, aparently, then dont return null. But if a do

```
tt.setText("some random text here");
```

it doesn't work.

I think I'm not doing something right. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are not accessing current view but you are creating new one:

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_activity, null);
```

you don't need this two lines at all since you can access current view components directly

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toptext);
TextView bt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
```

and then set the values.

Of course, since getNews() method is called by non-ui thread, all the code inside it that is touching UI must be called via runOnUiThread :

```
public void getNews() {
    // ...
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
                TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView bt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);

                tt.setText("some random text here");
                //...
            }
        });
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify where your `LinearLayout` will go within the `RelativeLayout`.  For example, you should probably specify:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/logoTop"
```

Also, if you want the items within the `LinearLayout` to be aligned vertically, you need to set

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

This would make your total `LinearLayout` declaration look something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logoTop"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >
```

Comment: Thank you! But now the problem is that the setText() and setImageBitmap() don't change anything

Comment: That's a different question =)  Make sure you run the setters on the Ui thread.  `Activity` has a method conveniently called `runOnUiThread` that takes a `Runnable` object.